# error : already has a primary key defined on it in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to check if the `primary key clustered index` exist before I create It and getting the following error

Table `ciqRestatementType` already has a primary key defined on it.
    Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
               WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'pk_ciqRestatementType') 
               AND type in (N'U'))
        ALTER TABLE [ciqRestatementType] 
        ADD CONSTRAINT [pk_ciqRestatementType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
      ( [restatementTypeId] ASC)
```

Could somebody tell me what the problem is ?

Comment: Should be `Type in (N'PK')`

Comment: Also what if the PK has a different name? You should be checking if the table has a primary key... it shouldn't matter what the previous name was. But perhaps you should have a different flow - if the PK has a different name, is on different columns, etc. you can bail out and require manual inspection / intervention.

Comment: No Aaron these tables pk wont change. It will be always the same

Comment: @Tom I'd be very careful about assumptions like always and never...

Comment: Did you look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql)  for sys.objects? Type 'U' is "Table (user-defined)". Use the correct value mentioned by wei. And don't assume that the primary key is also the clustered index.